# Excel VBA, autofilter error: no cells are found

Tags: excel, vba

My Macro proceeds as coded on the 1st day (Jun 1), but when I already put "2" as Jun 2, I get this error:

"No cells are found"

Here is my code that tries to sum all amount on the given date. But for June 2, there'll be no data (no transaction, no amount), so I want it to return the value 0. But instead, that error pops up.

```
  ElseIf ws.Cells(R, 2).Value = "SECURITY" And ws.Cells(R, 3).Value = "C/A# 0461-025792-001" Then
ws25.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Day & "-" & Monthw & "-" & Year1
ADD = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws25.Range("C4:C1500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
ws.Cells(R, 5).Value = ADD
ws25.Range("A4").AutoFilter

ws25.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Day & "-" & Monthw & "-" & Year1
MIN = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws25.Range("D1:D1500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
ws.Cells(R, 11).Value = -MIN
ws25.Range("A4").AutoFilter
```

Hope you can help! Thanks!

Comment: Is SUMIFS not working? SUM doesn't disregard hidden cells. You might try SUBTOTAL or AGGREGATE for that or work through the discontiguous Areas on xlCellTypeVisible.

Comment: @Arianne-gale-cruz: have you tried stepping through the code using [F8 debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) to check the values of the *Autofilter* ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check that data exists for the entered date before trying to use `Autofilter`? That way t=you can avoid the error

Comment: Hi! That code is only a part of my entire procedure. That is actually one bank statement, and I have about 35 bank statement with that same code. Some have a particular date, say, June 2, but some has none.

Comment: Here is the exact problem, of the 35 bank statements that I run, I only encountered the error in that one bank statement only. All the other bank statements are working properly even though they also don't have that particular date.